# Count consecutive null rows from a joined table

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
members:
----------------------------------------------
| member_id | member_name | member_join_date |
----------------------------------------------  

events:
-------------------------
| event_id | event_name |
-------------------------

event_dates:
--------------------------------------
| event_id | event_date | event_week |
--------------------------------------

attendance:
------------------------------------------------------------
| member_id | event_id | attendance_date | attendance_week |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I have members who joined the organization at a certain time and they may attend weekly events (the occurrences of which are monitored by the `event_dates` table)

What I want to do is get all members that have at least 3-consecutive absences

I did all I could and I think I have each part of the query but don't know how to merge them together.

Get all events that they could've attended:

```
    SELECT
      m.member_id AS id,
      ed.event_id,
      ed.event_week
    FROM
      members AS m
      LEFT JOIN
        event_dates AS ed
        ON
          ed.event_date >= m.member_join_date
```

Get all the events they actually attended:

```
    SELECT
      m.member_id AS id,
      a.event_id
    FROM
      members AS m
      LEFT JOIN
        attendance AS a
        ON
          a.member_id = m.member_id
```

And probably the answer to this question if I manage to merge the two queries into one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321670/count-of-consecutive-not-null-values

But this time I want to count `NULL` values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem. And when I have my SQL Server hat on, I often solve this kind of problem with two `ROW_NUMBER()` calls. Sadly, MySQL, unlike many other major SQL products, does not support `ROW_NUMBER()`, nor any other ranking function. To make up for that, however, you can use variable assignment in SELECTs, which MySQL does support (unlike many other major SQL products).

Below is a [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09e6a/23) followed by an explanation:

```
SELECT
  member_id,
  member_name,
  event_id,
  COUNT(*) AS consecutive_times_missed,
  MIN(event_date) AS first_date_missed,
  MAX(event_date) AS last_date_missed
FROM (
  SELECT
    member_id,
    member_name,
    event_id,
    event_date,
    is_missed,
    @occ_ranking := (event_id = @last_event) * (member_id = @last_member) * @occ_ranking + 1,
    @att_ranking := (event_id = @last_event) * (member_id = @last_member)
                                             * (is_missed = @last_missed) * @att_ranking + 1,
    @occ_ranking - @att_ranking AS grp,
    @last_member := member_id,
    @last_event  := event_id,
    @last_missed := is_missed
  FROM (
    SELECT
      m.member_id,
      m.member_name,
      e.event_id,
      e.event_date,
      (a.attendance_date IS NULL) AS is_missed
    FROM       members     m
    INNER JOIN event_dates e ON m.member_join_date <= e.event_date
    LEFT  JOIN attendance  a ON m.member_id = a.member_id
                            AND e.event_id = a.event_id
                            AND e.event_date = a.attendance_date,
    (
      SELECT
        @occ_ranking := 0,
        @att_ranking := 0,
        @last_member := 0,
        @last_event  := 0,
        @last_missed := 0
    ) v
    ORDER BY
      m.member_id,
      e.event_date
  ) s
) s
WHERE
  is_missed = 1
GROUP BY
  member_id,
  member_name,
  event_id,
  grp
HAVING
  COUNT(*) >= 3
;
```

Basically, you start with joining `members` and `event_dates` to get all the event occurrences the members could have attended based on their membership dates. Then you throw in the `attendance` table (via a left join) to flag the missed occurrences. Here's an example of what you get by this time:

```
member_id  event_id  event_date  is_missed
---------  --------  ----------  ---------
1          1         2012-07-10  0
2          1         2012-07-10  1
1          1         2012-07-14  0
2          1         2012-07-14  1
…          …         …           …
```

At this point, the resulting set needs to be sorted by `member_id, event_id`, because that is crucial to the subsequent rankings calculation.

Two different rankings are produced for every row. One is a ranking within the row's partition of `(member_id, event_id)` (it is reset as soon as a new event or a new member is encountered). The other is a ranking within the specific group of consecutive event occurrences, either attended or missed, that the row belongs to (this ranking, in addition to being reset upon coming across a new member or event, also gets reset whenever the other group is encountered). And so you get something like this:

```
member_id  event_id  event_date  is_missed  ranking1  ranking2
---------  --------  ----------  ---------  --------  --------
…          …         …           …          …         …
1          1         2012-07-27  0          4         4
1          1         2012-07-28  0          5         5
1          1         2012-07-29  1          6         1
2          1         2012-07-10  1          1         1
2          1         2012-07-14  1          2         2
2          1         2012-07-25  1          3         3
2          1         2012-07-27  0          4         1
…          …         …           …          …         …
```

As you may have noticed, the difference between the two ranking numbers is constant throughout the particular group of consecutive event occurrences of the same kind ("attended" or "missed") and is also unique for that group within its partition. Therefore, every such group can be identified by `member_id`, `event_id` and the just mentioned difference.

And it now remains simply to filter the events leaving just the missed ones, group the rows and get the necessary aggregated data, like the number of rows and, possibly, as in the query above, the dates of the first and the last event occurrence in the group. The number of rows is also used in an additional filter condition to omit groups with fewer rows than required.

Comment: Sorry it took a while to select the answer, I was modifying the query a bit more. I noticed that derived tables do not use indeces though. So if the lowest level `JOIN` returns a LOT of rows I'd take a big performance hit right?

Comment: @RolandoCruz: Seems probable. Not sure, however, what index or indices to suggest in this situation to make sure they would be efficiently used (not very good at query tuning yet, sorry). If I had to tune this myself, I'd likely be taking into account the GROUP BY columns as well as the ORDER BY ones, although either would seem to me a tricky bit to account for, as those columns belong to different tables.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that the `(event_id, event_date)` is the primary or a unique key in `event_dates` table):

```
SELECT
  m.member_id AS id,
  ed_start.event_id,
  ed_start.event_date AS miss_start,
  ed_end.event_date AS miss_end,
  COUNT(*) AS consecutive_misses
FROM
  members AS m
  JOIN
    event_dates AS ed_start
    ON
      ed_start.event_date >= m.member_join_date
  JOIN
    event_dates AS ed_end
    ON  ed_end.event_id = ed_start.event_id
    AND ed_end.event_date >= ed_start.event_date
  JOIN
    event_dates AS ed_mid
    ON  ed_mid.event_id = ed_start.event_id
    AND ed_mid.event_date >= ed_start.event_date
    AND ed_mid.event_date <= ed_end.event_date
  LEFT JOIN
    attendance AS a
    ON  a.member_id = m.member_id
    AND a.event_id = ed_mid.event_id
    AND a.attendance_date = ed_mid.event_date
GROUP BY 
    m.member_id,
    ed_start.event_id,
    ed_start.event_date,
    ed_end.event_date
HAVING
    COUNT(*) >= 3
   AND
    COUNT(a.attendance_date) = 0 ;
```

Test in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09e6a/7)**

---

The above may give (too many) multiple results if the consecutive misses are more than 3. So, If you want only the members and events they missed but not when they missed attendance, replace the `SELECT` with (test: **[SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dafa/3)**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  m.member_id AS id,
  ed.event_id,
FROM
  ...
```

You could also wrap the query (as a derived table) inside an external query and do another grouping for this to work (test: **[SQL-Fiddle-3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dafa/6)**)

---

And if you want only the members and not the events they missed nor when they missed attendance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  m.member_id AS id
FROM
  ...
```

Comment: Hmmmm.. It returns 0 rows :)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f509/1/0

Comment: @Rolando: Yes, wrong column in the `COUNT()=0`. Corrected now.

Comment: Haven't yet figured out how this works, but it [doesn't seem to find](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09e6a/1) the employees who missed the *first* 3 occurrences of an event. (In that example, I expected the employee ID=2 to be returned.)

Comment: @Andriy: Yeah, it was wrong. It needed (one more!) join. I don't expect this to be efficient. No idea how it could be rewritten in an elegant manner ...

Comment: And if the misses are more than 3 in a row, it returns too many results. It needs to be embedded as a derived table to get those out (or use the last 2 `DISTINCT` versions)

Comment: @ypercube, yes, I noticed that too. Those incurring more than 3 consecutive absences return multiple rows and I've been trying to figure out up to this moment :D